# MSAccess: Global vs Local Variable Declaration

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access app with a couple dozen modules.   I have been declaring variable afresh in each new module, minus the variable requiring global scope.  I use Option Explicit everywhere.

Question:  Would it be poor practice to declare my common local variables as globals, even though the scope is only local?.  Just a matter of convenience, I suppose:

Examples of variables I declare in each and every module:

```
Dim strMsg as String
Dim strSQL as String
Dim N, N1, N2 as Integer
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
```

Any guidance or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would still want to keep those kinds of variables local. What if you are in `Module1` and set `strMsg` then you call a function in `Module2` from `Module1` and you modify `strMsg` in `Module2`. having returned to `Module1` you would expect that no state in `Module1` to have changed but now your `strMsg` is different. Sure these are basically static classes and don't have state per-se but it's usually best to keep everything as close to the calling code as possible. if you don't have a really compelling reason to need these variables to be global then keep them local.

Comment: +1 Good reasoning, especially for "scratch" variables like `N`. Unexpected side-effects from calling other routines could make debugging *much* more difficult.

Comment: And remember every global variable drain resources.