# Initiating CurrentDb object at the form level

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have many Subs in a form with the following code

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim strSQL as String
db.Execute strSQL
```

Is it good practice to initialize `db` at the "form level" i.e. write first two lines of code above only once? If so, how should I do it?

This is somewhat different from [MSAccess: Global vs Local Variable Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709125/msaccess-global-vs-local-variable-declaration)

Comment: For this limited scope you could create form variables and initialize at open. Or you could create a function with the above code and pass it the sql string to execute.

Comment: I always offload to a standard module.  Easier to find things without form-based event-handlers competing for space.  I can have public variables and everything is more stable.  But it's prolly old-school.  (I doubt SO is good for this rather broad question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this function in a Module:

```
Public Function currDB() As Database
    Static currDB_v As Database

    If currDB_v Is Nothing Then
        Set currDB_v = CurrentDb
    End If

    Set currDB = currDB_v

End Function
```

And call `CurrDB.Execute`

If you have no error handling as you posted in Q, then you can also write function:

```
Public Sub ExecSQL(SQL as string)
    CurrDB.Execute SQL
End Sub
```